# How to use + or & in \section titles

Tags: symbols

I'm using the scrreprt package and I can't figure out how to use the "+" and the "&" symbol in the title of a subsection.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \section{Many supers}
    Text
    %Source of the problem
    \subsection{Super+ & Hyper}
    Text
\end{document}
```

is what I'd use ideally, but that gives an error with a "misplaced alignment tab character"

I googled a lot and tried quite a lot of variations like:

```
\subsection{Super\+ \& Hyper}
\subsection{Super\text{+ &} Hyper}
\subsection{Super\[+ &\] Hyper}
```

and more - nothing I tried works. Especially the & poses a big problem. The + actually worked with

```
\text{+}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small document that shows your problem. Just edit your question and add the code.

Comment: I have no problems doing `\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\section{test + \& test}
bla
\end{document}`

Comment: Added some more code and packages I'm using.

Comment: Your above example works for me with `\subsection{Super+ \& Hyper}`

Comment: I bet that `\subsection{Super+ \& Hyper}` will work.

Comment: Yeah thanks - It works for me now too - I could have sworn I did it this way at least twice in the last hour. I have no idea what went wrong. Thanks for your help @samcarter and egreg

Comment: @Zackebuh Just a guess: but if there are errors in section titles and similar they survive in the auxiliary files for a few compilations, so when testing the new new solution you either have to clean the auxiliary files or compile multiple times. So maybe when you tried you did not  compile often enough?

Comment: please don't edit the question to add the answer it makes the archived page rather confusing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay - I cleaned it all up - hope it's fine now

Comment: @samcarter Yes, that might have actually been the case. I don't know if I compiled several times after I tried a fix.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
\subsection{Super+ \& Hyper}
```

Thanks to @samcarter and @egreg

Comment: I kind of agree that this question might be a "duplicate" - but on the other hand the problem in this case came from the \section and \subsection argument, which needed several compilations due to auxiliary files. Seems relevant to me.